# My neutral Ok button is not showing in my alert dialog for Samsung S5 and J700

Tags: android

Trying to build a mobile application and have tested across some devices, but when it comes to Samsung S5 Notebook and J700 mobile phones, both have been failing because they have failed to display the neutral button in the application, please who might have the slightest clue to solving this particular issue. Thanks. 
Here is a sample code below;

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)//new Alert Dialog
            .setTitle("Delete entry")//set title
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    // continue with delete
                }
             })`enter code here`
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
             .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with `.setPositiveButton` this should work.

Check if you are using AlertDialog from support library?

Comment: If i use AlertDialog from a support library, should that affect it?, though i am not using it

Comment: That might be issue check with support import. You also not calling `create()` method on builder object before `show()`.

Answer (score 0):

just replace with this -

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)//new Alert Dialog
            .setTitle("Delete entry")//set title
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete

                }
            })

            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
//                    .show();
    AlertDialog d = builder.create();
    d.show();
```

Comment: use this import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

Comment: You do not need to call `create`, `show` call it internally: `final AlertDialog dialog = create(); dialog.show();`

Comment: At Atahar Hossain, I am using android.app.AlertDialog, i guess a big differenceexit between both

Comment: I suggest you to use android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog instead of android.app.AlertDialog, and in that case, the above code will produce the result what you expected.

Comment: @Atahir Hossain, Please my progress dialog shows in API 17 beloe but does not show in API23, Please how do i go about styling it.

Comment: Please make sure, whether you are using android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog or android.app.AlertDialog. If you import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog for your AlertDialog , then it also works in API 23